# Showing that a sequence $\left(x_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in a metric space is bounded iff the set of its elements is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space, $\left(x_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence in $X$ and $E = \{x_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. I want to show that $\left(x_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded iff $E$ is bounded. So far I can show the "if" part, but I am stuck at the "only if".

To show "if", suppose $\left(x_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded, i.e. $\exists z \in X, r > 0: \forall n \in \mathbb{N}: x_n \in \mathcal{B}_r(z)$. Let $x_k, x_l \in E$. Then,
$d(x_k, x_l) \leq d(x_k, z) + d(z, x_l) \leq r + r \Longleftrightarrow \sup \{d(x_k, x_l)\mid k, l \in \mathbb{N}\} \leq 2r < \infty$. Hence $\mathrm{diam}(E) \leq 2r < \infty$, that is $E$ is bounded.

To show the "only if", suppose  that $\mathrm{diam}(E) = C < \infty$. Let $z \in X$ and set $r = \mathrm{dist}(z, E) + \mathrm{diam}(E)$, so that the ball centered at $z$ can reach every element of $E$. Again, let $x_k, x_l \in E$, so that $d(x_k, z) \leq d(x_k, x_l) + d(x_l, z)$. (And from here on one must show that $d(x_k, z) \leq r$).

So, currently I am stuck at finishing the last inequality. How should I proceed?

Comment: Maybe I'm braindead or I'm reading the question wrong, but if the *definition* of "$\left(x_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded" is not " $E = \{x_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is bounded", then *what is* the definition of "$\left(x_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded"? In other words, what is your definition of "$\left(x_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded", and what is your definition of " $E = \{x_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is bounded"?

Comment: I agree with the above comment. Bit confused. isnt  $E=\{x_n\}$

Comment: @AdamRubinson from the attempt, it seems that these definitions are indeed different here. A set $E$ is said to be bounded if its diameter is finite, and a sequence is bounded if it is inside some $\mathcal B_r(z)$.

Comment: Okay, although OP should have stated those definitions in his question.

Comment: @AdamRubinson The reading material I am using defines a set $A$ to be bounded if its diameter, $\mathrm{diam}(A) = \inf\{d(a_1, a_2)\mid a_1, a_2 \in A\}$ is finite, and a sequence $\left(x_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ to be bounded if it is contained in some ball $B_r(z), z \in X, r > 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost done:
Observe that
$$d(x_k,x_l)\leq \mathrm{diam}(E)$$
holds (by using the definitions of $\mathrm{diam}$).
Thus, we have
$$
d(x_k,z) \leq \mathrm{diam}(E)+ d(x_l,z).
$$
By taking the infimum over $x_l\in E$, we get
$$
d(x_k,z)= \inf_{x_l\in E} d(x_k,z) \leq \mathrm{diam}(E)+ \inf_{x_l\in E} d(x_l,z)
= \mathrm{diam}(E)+ \mathrm{dist}(z,E) = r.
$$

Comment: Are you sure that $d(x_l, z) \leq \mathrm{dist}(z, E) = \inf \{d(z, e) \mid e \in E\}$ holds true? Since could it be that $x_l$ is some point further away than the one that gives $\mathrm{dist}(z, E)$?

Comment: @Qwaster you are correct, this was wrong. It can be fixed by taking the infimum over all $x_l\in E$, see current version of the answer (the infimum then leads to $\mathrm{dist}(x_l,z)$).

Comment: Why can we take the $\inf$ only from the RHS of the last inequality? I have only ever seen $\sup$ and $\inf$ to be taken from both sides of the equation, but I am not that proficient with $\sup$ and $\inf$ yet.

Comment: @Qwaster the LHS does not depend on $x_l$. So if we apply the infimum over $x_l$, it stays the same.

Comment: I think I understand now. So as the $x_l$ was an intermediary member to begin with (we started from $d(x_k, z)$), the triangle inequality must hold for all such intermediaries, hence the infimum is permitted.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\textrm{diam}(E) = C < +\infty$, so $E$ is bounded in the diameter sense, let $z=x_1$ and $r= C+1 >0$. Then I claim that all points of $(x_n)_{n \in \Bbb N}$ are in $B_r(z)$: Let $x_m$ be arbitrary, then $d(x_1, x_m) \le \textrm{diam}(E)$ as the diameter is an upper bound for *all* the distances between members of $E$. In particular $d(z,x_m) < r$ and so $x_m \in B_r(z)$ and we're done.

Comment: Ah, a brilliant solution! I somehow did not want to force the choice of $z$ to be a member of the sequence. But any member of the sequence is a member of $X$, hence there is nothing that disallows one to choose a $z$ of one's liking.

Comment: @Qwaster Nothing brillaint about it. But indeed we have a lot of choice in picking $z$ and $r$ and we should exploit that to make it as easy as we can on ourselves..